# C# accessing middle class members - not base

Tags: c#, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have multiple classes inheritance structure in my code. Class D inherits from class C which inherits from class B which inherits from base class A. Each of them has TryParse method.

My question is there any way to access directly the class you are deriving from, not base? 
If I am correct code base.TryParse in class D will call A.TryParse.
How do I access C.TryParse or B.TryParse from class D?

I'll be more specific by describing problem I am trying to solve.

I have filenames that are composed of many things.
In general it goes like this:

```
GalleryName-GroupName-PictureName-Dimensions.jpg   // picture itself

Example: Domestic-Animals-Dogs-Catching-a-Frisbee-800x600.jpg
GalleryName: Domestic-Animals
GroupName: Dogs
PictureName: Catching-a-Frisbee
Dimensions: 800x600
Extension: jpg

and more variations:
GalleryName-GroupName-PictureName-Dimensions.htm  // related htm file
GalleryName-GroupName-PictureName-Dimensions-th.jpg // thumb - notice the -th
```

I will need to work with shorter parts of that complex name as well - alsmot every possible variation:

- GeneralFileName.Extension
- PictureName-Dimension.Extension
- GroupName-PictureName-Dimensions.Extension
- GalleryName-GroupName-PictureName-Dimensions.Extension
- GalleryName-GroupName-PictureName-Dimensions-th.Extension

I wanted to solve it like this.

```
public struct PictureDimension
{
   public int Width;
   public int Height;

   public static bool TryParse( string parseString, out PictureDimension result ) 
   {
      // get it done 
   }
}

class FileNameWithExtension
{
   public string FileName { get; private set; }
   public string Extension { get; private set; }

   public bool TryParse( string parseString ) 
   {
      // extract filename from extension 
   }

}


class PictureDimensionExtensionName : FileNameWithExtension
{
        // inhereted from FileNameWithExtension
//        public string FileName { get; private set; }
//        public string Extension { get; private set; }
        public string PictureName { get; private set; }
        public PictureDimension Dimension { get; private set; }

   public new bool TryParse( string parseString ) 
   {
      base.TryParse( parseString );
      // get rest of it done
   }

   }
}

class GroupPictureDimensionExtensionName : PictureDimensionExtensionName
{
        // inhereted from PictureDimensionExtensionName
//        public string FileName { get; private set; }
//        public string Extension { get; private set; }
//        public string PictureName { get; private set; }
//        public PictureDimension Dimension { get; private set; }
        public string GroupName { get; private set; }

   public new bool TryParse( string parseString ) 
   {
    ==>   firstAboveBase.TryParse( string parseString );
      // get rest of it done 
   }
}

class GalleryGroupPictureDimensionExtensionName : 
           GroupPictureDimensionExtensionName
{
   public string GalleryName { get; private set; }

   public new bool TryParse( string parseString ) 
   {
    ==>   secondAboveBase.TryParse( string parseString );
      // get rest of it done 
   }
}
```

I am not aware of any keywords like firstAboveBase and secondAboveBase. Is there any way to access directly the class you are deriving from, not base?

Comment: Your struct should be immutable.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `new`. Don't do that. That gets rid of polymorphism entirely, which surely isn't what you're intending. Shadowing members makes code *much* harder to follow, in my experience - why are you doing it?

However, if you call `base.Foo` from class `D` which derives from class `C` and which exposes a `Foo` method, it *will* call `C.Foo`.

Sample code:

```
using System;

class A
{
    public virtual string Foo() { return "A"; }
}

class B : A
{
    public override string Foo() { return "B"; }
}

class C : B
{
    public override string Foo() { return "C"; }
}

class D : C
{
    public override string Foo() { return "D"; }

    public void ShowBaseFoo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("base.Foo() from D: {0}", base.Foo());
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new D().ShowBaseFoo();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
base.Foo() from D: C
```

Answer (score 1):

> directly the class you are deriving from, not base?

`base` already designates the immediate class you are deriving from.

Otherwise `base` would always mean `System.Object` (the mother of all classes).

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, you can, since you aren't overriding them.

```
((FileNameWithExtension)this).TryParse(...);
```

However, it is impossible to call a grandparent version of an overridden method.

Comment: Thank you. What if I was overriding them? How would I access them then?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to, unless you add separately-named methods to the parent classes.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to just do a cast to the parent type you need?

```
D myVar = New D();
((B)myVar).TryParse(...)
```